# Server Information Script hangs on read

Tags: bash

```
read -p "Which server do you want to know about: "
read var_server
echo $var_server
for $var_server
  do
    $echo ping -a $var_server
    $ehco nmap -O $var_server
done
```

My script hangs on the "read var server" when i execute with sh -x, could anyone advise thanks. It just stops and sits on the

```
+ read var_server
```

Not sure where i am going wrong

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate `read` calls. Combine them into one single call so you're only prompted for one piece of information:

```
read -p "Which server do you want to know about: " var_server
```

Also the `for` loop is nonsensical. You've only got one server, there's nothing to loop over, so delete the loop. Then you wrote `$echo` and `$ehco` instead of `echo`. So change the entire for loop to just these two lines:

```
echo ping -a $var_server
echo nmap -O $var_server
```

Comment: tried that as well, but then i get: 

serverInfo.sh: line 9: `$var_server': not a valid identifier

Comment: That was it the loop was mucking it up, thanks a lot mate will mark correct when it lets me.

Comment: If your script ever gets to `for $var_server`, I would expect an error.  Because `$var_server` is not a valid identifier.